# How to convert yolo annotations to coco format. Json?

Tags: image, deep-learning, object-detection, data-annotations, annotation-processing

I want to convert my labels  in yolo format to coco format
I have tried
https://github.com/Taeyoung96/Yolo-to-COCO-format-converter
And
Pylabel
They all have a bugs.

I want to train on detectron 2 but it fails to load the dataset because of the wrong json file.

Thanks everybody

Comment: Could you elaborate on the error you get? Also, provide file examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [globox](https://github.com/laclouis5/globox) package (disclaimer: I'm the author). This should ressemble something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import globox


def main() -> None:
  path = Path("/path/to/annotations/")  # Where the .txt files are
  save_file = Path("coco.json")

  annotations = globox.AnnotationSet.from_yolo(gts_path)
  annotations.save_coco(save_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you need to map the labels using a `.name` file:

```py
names_file = Path("/path/to/classes.names")
names = AnnotationSet.parse_names_file(names_file)
annotations.map_labels(names)
```

you can check the documentation for other formats (Yolo Darknet, Yolo v8, etc.).

Comment: Hello thanks for your help but i get this error   File "C:\Users\Nima\Desktop\ObjectDetectionEval-master\ObjectDetectionEval\boundingbox.py", line 186, in <genexpr>
    coords = (float(c) for c in coords)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: An annotation file may be malformed, could you investigate which one is the culprit and post it here please?

Comment: I tracked down the bug my labels in the first line have an space in end and that makes your code not to work example:0 0.5375 0.8875 0.10625 0.212** this * characters are spaces . is there any way to strip end of the lines in your code

Comment: I will send an example of the label file your GitHub repository issues

Comment: Yes, line 175 of `boundingbox.py` you can add a `.strip()` after the `.split()`, this should solve the issue. I'll fix the bug in the repo.

Comment: before*, not after

Comment: There is no bug in your repo it was bug in my dataset . i fixed my dataset with script and your code worked like charm

Comment: Sure, but fixing it makes my repo more robust to these kind of dataset bugs. You can accept my answer if it solved your issue, thanks!

Comment: There is little problem: there is no method named Annotation.parse_names_file(names_file) is my repo outdated?  and I want to map categories from 1 instead of zero is there anyway for this

Comment: The function name is `parse_names_file()`. You can use the `map_labels()` method to map to different labels.